# How to open a Play app in IntelliJ IDEA from the command line?

Tags: java, scala, command-line, intellij-idea, playframework

After I create a new [Play](http://www.playframework.org/) app

```
$ play new myapp
$ cd myapp/
$ play idealize
$ ls
app       conf      lib       myapp.iml public    test
```

I can open a file (only if an IDEA project is already opened) using

```
$ alias "ij=open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA*.app"
$ ij app/controllers/Application.java
```

Is there a nice way to create a new (or open an existing) Play project from the command line? I could write a simple script which creates the necessary XML-files (myapp.ipr, myapp.iws) and then opens the project by

```
$ ij myapp.ipr
```

but I hope this is unnecessary (or has been already done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked the framework and made the necessary changes to make this possible. See https://github.com/andreif/play/commit/ec70ab8162620a0c9ba5ca7195fc3c51d7de91b1 (note, the branch is called [**idea_project**](https://github.com/andreif/play/tree/idea_project)!)

This commit adds command `ideaproj` which creates Module, Project and Workspace files of a very simple structure. If you are using OS X, the command will also try to open the project in **all(!)** IDEA apps located at `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA*.app`. So adjust the python script in case if you have more than one IDEA app there. Additionally, you will probably want to change the default workspace layout. Have a look at `iwsTemplate.xml` and modify it to fit your preferences.

Usage: run the following command in the app directory to create IDEA project files (and open them):

```
play ideaproj
```

Note, that it will **overwrite** existing project files! If the IDEA project is already opened at the time you run this command again, then IDEA will ask you if you want to reload the project.

I have also added the following two commits:

- [[#770] Add sources when generating module for IntelliJ IDEA](https://github.com/playframework/play/pull/273)
- [[#923] Fix play idealize command to add dependent libs](https://github.com/playframework/play/pull/270)

If you want to start using this command now, then copy files [`intellij.py`](https://github.com/andreif/play/blob/idea_project/framework/pym/play/commands/intellij.py), [`iprTemplate.xml`](https://github.com/andreif/play/blob/idea_project/resources/idea/iprTemplate.xml), and [`iwsTemplate.xml`](https://github.com/andreif/play/blob/idea_project/resources/idea/iwsTemplate.xml) to your Play framework directory (to the corresponding locations!).

EDIT: I have made two more commits to fix project tree in the workspace template, so that it expands first time you open the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you can create the project files as you mention, idealize generates an Idea Module file for the Play project, so it should be as simple as to integrate that Module in your project file and open the project.

If you do that, please publish it as a Module in Play, it would be handy :)